# Where does wingetcreate save new manifests to?

Tags: winget

I created and submitted a new winget package manifest to Microsoft's winget-pkgs github repository using Microsoft's official CLI tool WinGetCreate by typing `wingetcreate new` and filling out the subsequent forms. On the pull request page I'm asked to confirm that I have validated and tested the manifest locally.

The problem is that I don't know if and where wingetcreate has saved the newly created manifest locally.

Answer (score 0):

Found the new manifest under `C:\Users\<my_username>\manifests`